# entityreference_autocomplete -- Return list that contains

Tags: forms, entities, ajax

I am quite new to the D7 Form API, but nevertheless I've got the basics up and running...

I have a custom content type (A) and I want users to be able to submit some Information, which in turn will create one node of that type (A).

This type (A) has an entity Reference field to another type (B) and would like to have an autocompletion field to assist the user.

I have this code:

```
$form['production_ref'] = array(
    '#type' => 'entityreference',
    '#title' => t('Production Reference'),
    '#description' => t('The Production referenced'),
    '#era_entity_type' => 'node',
    '#era_bundles' => array('typeA'),
    '#era_cardinality' => -1

    '#era_query_settings' => array(
        'limit' => 15, // Default is 50.
    /*  
        'property_conditions' => array(
          // 'entity property', 'filter value', 'operator'.
          array('uid', 30, '>'),
        ),

        'field_conditions' => array(
          // 'field name', 'column', 'value', 'op', 'delta', 'language'.
          array('field_test_field', 'value', 'test'),
        ),
  */
      )

  );
```

What creates an autocompletion field which is somehow working. But the result in the List looks somehow arbitray and does not return the relevant matches.

How can I tweak that, so that the query will take the typed Characters and tests each nodes´ (type B) title, if it contains these charackters?

I am using the "entityreference_autocomplete" module, which is hosted [here](https://github.com/drupalprojects/entityreference_autocomplete)

Thanks in Ahead!